# How i setup babel with express-generator to use es6

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I use this way to add babel in express-generator.

`"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start:dev": "nodemon ./bin/www --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
  }`

but I got an error for this. can anyone help me to solve this?

`import app from '../app';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Answer (score 3):

That's a way working right now

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- ./bin/www"
}
```

Install the following packages:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
}
```

Configuration for babel: using a `.babelrc` file with the following content

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```